# How to change the TabItem color when mouse is over?

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

I'm using `MahApp`, I've created the following `TabControl`:

```
<TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0">
<TabItem>
    <TabItem.Header>
        <Image Source="Images/Icon.png"></Image>
    </TabItem.Header>
    <TabItem.Content>
            <Grid>
                <Controls:Scheduler x:Name="Scheduler"/>
            </Grid>
    </TabItem.Content>
</TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

How can I handle the `MouseOver` event and change the color? Actually if I pass the mouse over the TabItem the user don't understand if the TabItem is clickable or not. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a `TabItem` Style as part of the `TabControl`. The `Style` will trigger based on `MouseOver`.

```
<TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0">
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                        <Border Name="Border" Background="Transparent">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                ContentSource="Header"
                                Margin="10,2"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" SourceName="Border">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.Resources>
    <TabItem>
        <TabItem.Header>
            <Image Source="Images/Icon.png"></Image>
        </TabItem.Header>
        <TabItem.Content>
            <Grid>

            </Grid>
        </TabItem.Content>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

**Edit**: If you want the color to persist when `TabItem` is selected, add this to the `ControlTemplate.Triggers`

```
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
            </Trigger>
```

Comment: Very good answer. Thanks :) Just a question: is possible hold the color when the tabItem is clicked?